# Are there mobile phones in North Korea?

Tags: economics, mobile-phones, geography, north-korea

Is it true that there are no mobile phones in North Korea? I have heard opposing views saying that there is a working mobile network that many people use and views that say there isn't any of them in the whole country.

Comment: I like this question, but it should reference - and ideally quote - an independent source of the claim (e.g. a newspaper article).

Comment: You can find some references from [wikipedia article on a matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_North_Korea#Mobile_phones) and on a [mobile provider page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koryolink)

Comment: @defaultlocale: You have all the ingredients of an answer there...

Comment: When I visited 2 years ago, people had cell phones. Visitors were not allowed to have theirs (they were kept at the border). I only visited the main cities.

Answer (score 12):

More clarification of international calls from North-Korea is given [here](http://www.northkoreatech.org/2013/03/27/mobile-internet-service-reportedly-stopped-for-tourists/), dated March 27, 2013.

> “3G access is no longer available for tourists to the DPRK. Sim cards can still be purchased to make international calls but no internet access is available,” the Beijing-based North Korean tourism specialist said in a short notice on its website.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 10):

According to a [recent BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-22308353)

> At the start of 2012 Koryolink claimed to have one million 3G subscribers.

[Koryolink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koryolink)  being North Koreas only 3G operator.

According to the same BBC article:

> The service can only be used to make voice calls, and all international calls are banned.

However tourists and visitors can use mobile data.

[This blog post from Google's Eric Schmidt](https://plus.google.com/+EricSchmidt/posts/UZnAUzpszHX#+EricSchmidt/posts/UZnAUzpszHX) also supports the view that while North Korea's mobile infrastructure is extremely limited, it does exist.

Answer (score 5):

It seems clear from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_North_Korea#Mobile_phones) that there are plenty of mobile phones. The issue of being able to make international calls is a different matter, but my original question seems answered.

Comment: So, why not award an answer? That would be helpful to others reaading this in future